# flutter cannot find method in method channel when working with fl_background_services package. How do i resolve this?

Tags: android, flutter

**Actual Error:**

```
Failed to invoke native method: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method nativeMethodName on channel com.example/my_channel)
```

**MainActivity.kt class**

```
private val CHANNEL = "com.example/my_channel"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
                    if (call.method == "nativeMethodName") {
                        // Call your native method here
                        val nativeResult = nativeMethodImplementation()
                        result.success(nativeResult)
                    } else {
                        result.notImplemented()
                    }
                }
    }

    private fun nativeMethodImplementation(): String {
        // Implement your native method logic
        return "Native method result"
    }
```

**callNativeMethod()** (calling this in onStart of service)

```
const platform = MethodChannel('com.example/my_channel');

Future<void> callNativeMethod() async {
  try {
    final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('nativeMethodName');
    print(result);
  } catch (e) {
    print('Failed to invoke native method: $e');
  }
}
```

I was trying to use camera package. It gave me same issue for availableCameras method. So i tried making my own native method.

Comment: have you tried restarting your app?

Comment: @pskink the code works fine for main isolate. its just with the new isolate that gets spawned by the package, has issues with method channel.

Comment: @AdarshSingh yes I know hot reload does not bring up changes. we have to do new build. thanks for considering visit.

Comment: create a plugin. search over official docs for how to. the plugins get registered automatically with new flutter engine that gets invoked in this onstart(separate isolate).using the method channels defined in this plugin you can talk with native code successfully, I have tested it.